# Converting real number to string in fortran f77

Tags: string, fortran, type-conversion, real-datatype

I'm running into the following error in fortran when trying to convert a real number to string.

```
iio: [-1] end of file
lately: writing sequential formatted internal IO
part of last string:   100000.   |
Abort (core dumped)
```

The below is the code where I'm getting the error. The value at which the above error is thrown in 99999.5

```
CHARACTER STRING*12
WRITE (STRING, '(G12.5)') VALUE
```

Why is this error thrown?

Comment: This should work. Show us more code. Don't you work with external files anywhere near? What compiler do you use?

Comment: Thats all the code it is written within a function which accepts the real value and returns a string.

Comment: That can't possibly be all the code, what you've shown us is not enough for compilation.

Comment: Maybe that's why it wont compile. That is _ALL_ the code.

Comment: okay what I meant was that was all the code which is causing the problem. the full code is something like this

Comment: `code`
CHARACTER*12 FUNCTION <FNNAME> (VAL)

CHARACTER STRING*12
WRITE (*,'(G12.5)') VAL
FNNAME = STRING

END
`code`

Comment: suggest you write a very small program that just calls that function. If it still throws that error post the entire program (edit your question to update).  If not you can conclude there is something else wrong perhaps evidently unrelated such as writing an array out of bounds someplace.

Comment: That's odd, I get the expected output `0.10000E+06` when calling that function with `PRINT*, RLSTR(99999.5)`, compiled with gfortran 4.7.2. I did assume you meant `WRITE(STRING,'(G12.5)') VAL`. The error has to be somewhere else. How do you use the converted value?